# Google closure base.js & modules

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to simply load google closure modules in my browser at development time, so I don't need any crazy advanced compilation.

my index.js contains:

```
goog.module("Widgets.index");

var Widgets$app = goog.require("Widgets.app");
/* rest of the code */
```

my index.html contains the following :

```
<script src="closure/base.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

I get the following in my console:

```
Module Widgets.index has been loaded incorrectly. 
Note, modules cannot be loaded as normal scripts.
They require some kind of pre-processing step
```

How do I pre-process the index.js?
I just want to load some simple google modules in my browser, this is development time. No need for any crazy (slow?) optimizations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry point is included on the page as a script but defines itself as a module. That's what the error message is telling you. Instead:

index.js

```
goog.provide("Widgets.index");

var Widgets$app = goog.require("Widgets.app");
/* rest of the code */
```